# TCP Connect Fails

Tags: tcp, winsock

I have two applications that talk via TCP, both of which run on Windows XP machines. The client is a third-party application for which I have only the executable, no source. The IP address of the server it connects to is set in a text configuration file. The server is an application I am writing.

All netmasks are 255.255.255.0.

In all cases, the client runs on 192.168.142.202.

I am seeing a case where if I run my server on 192.168.142.207, everything works, but if I move my server over to another machine on the same subnet (192.168.142.105), everything does not work fine. Specifically, the connection does not seem to get properly established. I have looked at what's going on in Wireshark and would like to request assistance interpeting what I see.

On the server side, I see the 3-way handshake: SYN, SYN/ACK, ACK. I get no error codes on the return of accept(), and netstat shows the connection as established.

On the client side, the connection does not seem to be established properly. This causes the client to reconnect periodically, and it will also occasionally close all of the not-correctly-connected sockets that get created as a result. When I look at the client side in Wireshark, I most often see a SYN, SYN, SYN pattern, rather that the expected 3-way handshake. Occassionally, the 3-way handshake does appear, but even then, the client doesn't seem to be happy with the connection because it closes it.

I will note that there are actually two TCP connections between the client and server. The other connection (i.e. not the problematic connection I described above) works just fine. The problematic connection has listening port 5004; the good connection has listening port 1234.

I have placed both .txt and .pcap versions of the client and server Wireshark captures at this link: https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=c5beaf58ac752bb0&resid=C5BEAF58AC752BB0!105&parid=root

As far as the physical network setup goes, there is one switch in between the client and server in the case that works, and there are two switches in between the client and server in the case that doesn't work. All ping tests are successful. There are no wireless connections involved; everything is wired.

All firewalls are off.

Does anybody have any thoughts on either what the problem is or what further data I could gather to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears this is not a network or network programming problem at all. I've figured out by trial and error that the third-party software that connects to me wants the machine it runs on to have a smaller IP address than the machine my software runs on. This seems completely arbitrary to me, but empirically, this very strongly appears to be the case. Arghhhh............

Thanks to any and all who may have spent time poring over the Wiresharks dumps I provided...